# Not getting cancel option in notification tray for android notification created using notificationBuilder

Tags: android, push-notification

This is the code I've used to create a notification.

```
    notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifications_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Upload")
                    .setContentText("image is being uploaded")
                    .setProgress(0, 0, true).setAutoCancel(true).build();
```

I am able to get the notification proprerly but not able to clear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you wrote:

```
setOngoing(true)
```

This means you want the notification to presist. **Solution?** Remove this line (or set it to `false`) and it will be dismissable.

Comment: @RajeswariRatala Happy to help!